# Сделать паджинацию средствами ajax-а Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

Всем привет,
Мне понадобилось в CI 3 сделать паджинацию средствами ajax-а.
Погуглив, я сделал переопределение обработчика ссылок:

```
$(document).on('click', "div.table_pagination a",function(){ 
    var urls = $(this).attr("href");
    var value_arr = urls.split( '/page_number/' );
    if ( value_arr.length == 2 ) { // we have page number
        load_related_users(value_arr[1])
    }
    return false;
});
```

И это работает, за исключением того что у паджинации изначально 1я страница как текст, а остальные как ссылки.
Как можно сделать чтобы ВСЕ ссылки паджинации были ссылками и текущую можно было выделить/задизейблидь ?

Урл page -   в приложении применяется, для других целей поэтому я использовал page_number и для вызова

```
$this->pagination->initialize($pagination_config);
```

я использовал массив:

```
$pagination_config::Array
(
    [per_page] => 4
    [uri_segment] => 5
    [num_links] => 10
    [use_page_numbers] => 1
    [page_query_string] => page_number
    [query_string_segment] => page_number
)
```

Также в ссылке различное число параметров передается, поэтому для указания номера страницы нужно использовать ключ по имени...

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Для ajax-запросов добавил в конфу паджинации

```
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '  <a href="#" class="active"  >';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = ' </a> ';
```

В результате и первый элемент паджинации стал ссылкой а не plain текст
но для нее не подключаются остальные параметры которые я передаю в

```
$pagination_config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'sys-admin/clients_edit_load_related_users' . $PageParametersWithSort.'/page_number';
```

где $PageParametersWithSort - несколько параметров в виде key/value

Первый элемент паджинации  имеет ссылку самой страницы

```
http://local-zntral.com/sys-admin/clients-edit/10
```

Как это исправить ?